# How can I slice out all of the array objects containing a value and storing them in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this array and I want to make a new array with those objects that have the swimming value in sports.

```
 var watchesArray = [
        {
          model: "Swim", 
          image:"",
          price: 149.99,
          sports:["Swimming", "Running"]
        },
        {
          model: "FR 10", 
          image:"",
          price: 129.99,
          sports:["Running"]

        },
        {
          model: "FR 15", 
          image:"",
          price: 199.99,
          sports:["Running"]

        },
    ];
```

So far I have this but I dont know how to add on to the sliced array with each go around in the for loop. How should I do this?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < watchesArrayLength; i++) {
        if (watchesArray[i].sports.indexOf("Swimming") > -1) {
            var runningWatchArray = watchesArray.slice(i);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want the swimming items removed from the original array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
watchesArray = [...];

var result = watchesArray.filter(function(watch) {
    return watch.sports.indexOf('Swimming') !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is

```
var runningWatchArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < watchesArrayLength; i++) {
    if (watchesArray[i].sports.indexOf("Swimming") > -1) {
        var watch = watchesArray.slice(i);
        runningWatchArray.push(watch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use forEach to loop through each item of the watchesArray...

```
var runningWatchArray = new Array();

watchesArray.forEach(function(watch){
      if (watch.sports.indexOf("Swimming") > -1) {
        runningWatchArray.push(watch);
      }
    }
```